# Tabulator vertical align headers when no headerfilter is set

Tags: css, tabulator

I have a table where I want some columns with a headerFilter and some without. The header of those columns without a filter are vertically aligned at the bottom.

[image: headers not aligned properly]

I only found a headerHozAlign in the documentation, but none for vertical alignment. Is there an easy way to do this or do I have to manipulate the css?

**Edit 1:**

I figured this has something to do with my stylesheets interacting. I use the bootstrap 4.5 css and the tabulator_bootstrap4 css.

```
<!-- Bootstrap 4.5.0 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Tabulator 4.9.3 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/tabulator_bootstrap4.min.css">
```

When i remove the bootstrap 4.5 css, the headings look the way they should (the rest of the website looks strange, obviously).

[image: Correct display of column headers and filters]

The Tabulator documentation just says

> A Bootstrap 4 compatible theme[...] The stylesheet maps the standard bootstrap table styling onto Tabulator. [Source](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/theme#framework-boot4)

Could this be the problem, that the tabulator stylesheet is just ment for bootstrap version 4?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some code that shows it failing ? Coz this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sce6b90q/) shows it shouldnt act like that at all

```
<leavemealone/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The code for my table is basically the same as in your fiddle. I edited my post and specified the problem, since it is probably caused by the different stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

The vertical alignment of column headers is set for the table as a whole using the `columnHeaderVertAlign` option in the table constructor:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
   columnHeaderVertAlign:"bottom",
});
```

It accepts a value of either `top`, `middle`, or `bottom`